# Creating User database error "no match for 'operator==' in....." --C++

Tags: c++, function, operators

I have been working on a user database in command prompt. It lets you add a user name and password and also sign in. When I compile it I get the error `no match for 'operator==' in`. I am not quite exactly sure what is causing the it. Also, I have stored all of it in a class.

**My header file is:**

```
#ifndef USER_PSW_H
#define USER_PSW_H
#include <string>


class User_Psw
{
    public:
        User_Psw();
        void addToDatabase();
        void getNameIndex();
        bool PasswordMatches();
        void UserCheck();
    protected:
    private:
        int sizeOfDatabase;
        int index;
        std::string Usernames;
        std::string Password;
        std::string username;
        std::string password;
};

#endif // USER_PSW_H
```

**The constructor is:**

```
User_Psw::User_Psw()
{
    const int SIZE = 100;
    index = 0;
    sizeOfDatabase = 0;
    Usernames[SIZE];
    Password[SIZE];
}
```

**The Function with the actual error is:**

```
void User_Psw::getNameIndex()
{
    for(int i=0; i < sizeOfDatabase; i++)
    {
        if (username == Usernames[i])
        {
            index = i;
        }
    }
}
```

With the actual line of code containing the error being `if (username == Usernames[i])`

I can also add more code snippets if It is required.

Comment: Does the constructor actually compile?

Comment: Well I think it does because I call the function with an error after the constructor.

Comment: Usernames[SIZE] isn't doing what you think it is; it's indexing into a string and ignoring the returned character, not declaring an array of size SIZE.  Thus, username and Usernames is the same type, but Usernames[i] returns a character and therefore cannot be compared to username with operator==. Look into using a vector<string> instead.

Comment: So use a vector in the _Usernames[SIZE]_ instead?

Comment: I am not quite sure how this is to be done. Where am I suppose to use the vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work because you're accessing `Usernames` like a vector when you actually defined the type as  `std::string`.

You want something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> Usernames;
```

Then you can access it like:

```
if (Usernames[i] == username) { // etc
```

Comment: Thank You! that makes sense so much more sense.